# Coq: easiest way to construct members of a decidable sigma type?

Tags: coq

Consider the following toy development:

```
Inductive IsEven: nat -> Prop :=
| is_even_z : IsEven 0
| is_even_S : forall n, IsEven n -> IsEven (S (S n)).

Definition EvenNat := {n | IsEven n}.
```

I'd like to create a function that, given a number that I personally know to be even, returns the corresponding value of type `EvenNat` with minimum fuss.

```
Example fortyTwo : EvenNat := mkEven 42.
```

Comment: How do you "know" `n` to be even? Is `n` concrete (like `1`)? Or do you have an assumption `IsEven n` in scope?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter I've edited to clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question, as originally stated, has an obvious answer.

*Question A:* If you have in your context a number `n` of type `nat` and a proof `knowledge` with statement `IsEven n`, how do you construct an object of type `EvenNat`?

you can simply construct an object of type `EvenNat` by writing the following expression

```
exist _ n knowledge
```

Or, if you really want to be explicit:

```
exist IsEven n knowledge
```

This is embodied in the following script

```
Inductive IsEven: nat -> Prop :=
| is_even_z : IsEven 0
| is_even_S : forall n, IsEven n -> IsEven (S (S n)).

Definition EvenNat := {n | IsEven n}.

Definition mkEven (n : nat) (knowledge : IsEven n) : EvenNat :=
  exist IsEven n knowledge.
```

Another reading of the question is as follows:

*Question B*: how do you construct an object of  type `EvenNat` from a known constant (like 42) which is obviously even to the naked eye?

Here is my elaboration of a solution sketched by Theo Winterhalter, using the device of type classes in full.

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Specif.

Inductive IsEven: nat -> Prop :=
| is_even_z : IsEven 0
| is_even_S : forall n, IsEven n -> IsEven (S (S n)).

Definition EvenNat := {n | IsEven n}.

Definition makeEvenNat (n : nat) (knowledge : IsEven n) : EvenNat :=
  exist IsEven n knowledge.

Class EvenClass n : Prop :=
  is_even : IsEven n.

#[export] Instance evenClass0 : EvenClass 0.
Proof.
apply is_even_z.
Qed.

#[export] Instance evenClassS n {h : EvenClass n}  : EvenClass (S (S n)).
Proof.
apply is_even_S; exact h.
Qed.

(* Using curly braces for the second argument h here deserves an
  explanation. *)
Definition mkEven (n : nat) {h : EvenClass n} : EvenNat :=
  exist IsEven n h.

Definition ev42 := mkEven 42.

Lemma ev42P : proj1_sig ev42 = 42.
Proof. easy. Qed.

Lemma IsEven42 : IsEven 42.
Proof. exact (proj2_sig ev42). Qed.
```

The explanation for using curly braces in the definition of `mkEven`
is that `mkEven` actually requires 2 arguments, but the second one
is not written by the user: it must be automatically constructed using the type class inference mechanism.  This proof must succeed for the object to be actually defined.

The definition of `ev42` is the answer of question *B*.  Note that a definition relying on  `mkEven 3` will fail, because no proof that 3 is even can be found.

```
Fail Definition ev3 := mkEven 3.
```

This code was tested with coq.8.15.0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your assumptions are but I would say one way of doing it is to use the automation capabilities of type classes:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Specif.

Inductive IsEven : nat -> Prop :=
| is_even_z : IsEven 0
| is_even_S : forall n, IsEven n -> IsEven (S (S n)).

Class EvenClass n :=
  is_even : IsEven n.

Definition EvenNat := { n | EvenClass n }.

Lemma EvenClass_IsEven :
  forall n, EvenClass n -> IsEven n.
Proof.
  intros n h.
  exact h.
Qed.

#[export] Hint Extern 1 (EvenClass 0) =>
  apply is_even_z
  : typeclass_instances.

#[export] Hint Extern 1 (EvenClass (S (S ?n))) =>
  apply is_even_S ; apply EvenClass_IsEven
  : typeclass_instances.

#[export] Hint Extern 1 (EvenClass (proj1_sig ?x)) =>
  apply proj2_sig
  : typeclass_instances.

#[export] Hint Extern 4 (EvenClass ?n) =>
  my_decision_procedure
  : typeclass_instances.
```

Instead of defining instances, I use the `Hint Extern` mechanism to inject any tactic I want to solve the goal. Assuming you have a tactic to decide your property you can use it there.
The natural number indicates the "cost" to each hint so the search will try to apply the hints with the lowest costs first.

Once you have this, the function you want is

```
Definition mkEven (n : nat) {h : EvenClass n} : EvenNat :=
  exist _ n h.
```

Then just writing `mkEven n` will trigger the proof search as described by the hints above.

```
Definition ev := mkEven 42.
```

---

To elaborate the difference between Yves's and my answer, I chose to use hints rather than class instances so that the proof search is not too greedy.

For instance, I force the search to only use `is_even_z` when I really want to prove `EvenClass 0`, as exemplified by the example below:

```
Goal exists n, EvenClass n.
Proof.
  eexists. Fail exact _.
Abort.

#[export] Instance foo : EvenClass 0.
Proof.
  exact _.
Qed.

Goal exists n, EvenClass n.
Proof.
  eexists. exact _.
Qed.
```

As you can see, in the first case, we have `EvenClass ?n` as a goal, and so the proof search does not find any candidate.
However, if we add the `0` case as a type class instance, then the proof search will succeed by unifying `?n` with `0`.
It is my belief that this is doing a bit too much for the case at hand here, but both solutions have their applications.

Comment: Nice solution.  Why not add a line to show how this solves the question?

Comment: In fact, I am trying to find how to finish the example, and I don't understand how this works, so if you finish the example with for instance a line of the form: `Defnition ev42 := myfunction 42`.  I will learn something!

Comment: I tried : `Definition mkeven n {h : EvenClass n} : EvenNat := exist IsEven n h.`  But then `Definition ev6 := mkeven 6.` fails (coq.8.15.0).

Comment: You are absolutely right. That'll teach me to test my answer before submitting it. It's now fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the very thoughtful response!

I'm trying to figure out how "proof search" being "too greedy" cashes out in practice. Do you have an example of a case where it makes a big difference, either in termination or performance?

Comment: Oh no, I did not mean for performance, I mean that it will unify evars when you might not want that. Also with my solution you can use any decision procedure of your choice.